# Category Axis Label Expression Alignment In jasper Report through Java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

Is there any way, to change Category Axis Label Expression's Alignment of a Chart in Jasper Report through Java Code.
I want Left alignment of Category Axis Label Expression. As shown the picture below, I want "hello" to be left aligned.

[image: given picture]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: What is hello?, the legend or a textField in your jrxml?

Comment: @PetterFriberg: I thought it was the domain axis label.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), included in the distribution, the changes below create a bar chart with an axis label having its location set to the `LOW_END`. For `PlotOrientation.VERTICAL`, that means aligned on the left.

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
    "Performance: JFreeSVG vs Batik",
    "$P{hello}" /* x-axis label*/,
    "Milliseconds" /* y-axis label */,
    dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
…
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setLabelLocation(AxisLabelLocation.LOW_END);
```

[image]

Try doing the same for the range axis to see the effect:

```
rangeAxis.setLabelLocation(AxisLabelLocation.LOW_END);
```