# Position x axis labels on top left and right

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dual axis jfreechart which has two x axis. By default the axis labels are appearing horizontally, I wanted to display them at the top left and right.

Comment: What happens when you change the `PlotOrientation`?

Comment: When i change the plot orientation from vertical to horizontal then it changes the display of plots from vertical bars to horizontal bars .But i don't wanted to change the plot orientation ,only wanted to change the two horizontal labels and place them on Top Left and right

Comment: I tried vertical axis.setLabelRotationAngle() but it did not help me with the label on the right side..On left side to some extent i was able to move

Answer (score 1):

To move the axis label, you can specify the desired [`AxisLabelLocation`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/AxisLabelLocation.html). As the default is `AxisLabelLocation.MIDDLE`, you can move it to the left using `LOW_END` like this:

```
xAxis1.setLabelLocation(AxisLabelLocation.LOW_END);
xAxis2.setLabelLocation(AxisLabelLocation.LOW_END);
```

The effect is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944238/230513).

[image: image1]

You can also change the [`AxisLocation`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/AxisLocation.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59003338/230513).

[image: image2]

As an aside, you can alter the label's text attributes as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808858/230513).

[image: image3]